# Passing parameters to jenkins from a url from linux

Tags: linux, jenkins

trying to post parameter request to jenkins for linux server.  Getting url not found 403-404.  Posting in browser works.  Same results w/ or w/o breadcrumb.  tried using python urllib.post and linux command line curl same result any thoughts?

Comment: Which URL are you posting to and where/how do you handle the parameter in the job?

Comment: Do you get a 403 or a 404? You can't get both